# Integral $\int_{0}^{2000} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{12s+0.02s^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{2000} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{12s+0.02s^{2}}}$$

I tried to substitute u = 12s + 0.02s^2, but that leaves me with an s when I take derivative. How would I do this without using integration by parts or partial fractions?

Comment: Complete the square. Then easiest is a hyperbolic cosine substitution.

Comment: Don't you mean $ds$ instead of $dx$?

Comment: yes, sorry @andrepd

Comment: @RoryDaulton: We are basically integrating $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+300s}}$. The quadratic is $(s+150)^2-150^2$. Make the substitution $s+150=150\cosh t$, and use the fact that $\cosh^2 t-1=\sinh^2 t$.  Everything collapses, we end up finding $\int (1)\,dt$. (I see that the question was removed, so undoubtedly you noted the above.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes, I realized that about a minute after posting my comment, then deleted it. Obviously you saw the comment. My bad!

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: An alternate ugly way is to use a secant substitution. Not terrible if we happen to have the integral of $\sec t$ among our memorized integrals. Lots of not fun otherwise.

Comment: Probably the most elegant way to evaluate integrals involving square-roots of quadratics is the method of [Euler substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).